Azure SQL Migration extension don't support MFA authentication
I'm trying to migrate an on-prem Sql Server database to Azure SQL Database. I'm using Azure Data Studio with Azure SQL Migration extension.
My problem is that Azure SQL Database is configured by dba's to use Entra MFA. On the target database screen I can't see how to provide only my MFA user name.

Is there any configuration on this extension so that it can accept MFA logins? The way it is I need to provide an account and password, which I don't have (and dba's wont tell me of course)
Thanks in advance
